# iOS 12: How to disable Message suggestion programmatically?

Tags: keyboard, ios12, imessage

My app send a security code and it show on the top of the keyboard automatically (the keyboard is set "Number Pad" type). 
How do I prevent it show the code programmatically? ( If I change keyboard type to "Numbers and Punctuation", the code will not show but I don't like this keyboard's type)

[image]